# Converting geom polygon to point x point y using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon, geometry

I have data geom polygon like this: 
`01060000C00100000001030000C00100000047000000635829FDD7685B400015F9448A80D33F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF4C255BAEF5685B4080B9FDA7F268D33F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF28249B4383695B4040D74AB4F31CD33F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF6B2E88CC656A5B40C00AACAE738ED23F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFD4D69EB26A6A5B40807C557C508BD23F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF17264B01176B5B400063223BF51CD23F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF6D5DAB56C96A5B40C05AA4CF0265D13F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF691AC9F5816A5B4000566C32CEF2D03F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF66D7E6943A6A5B40405134959980D03F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF679F4960C8695B40C04600D6CE23D03F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF566B8A956B695B408082C80E69D5CF3F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF56DA80A707695B40008DDE98C17FCF3F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF68D6A23DF2685B400082A6FB8C0DCF3F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF5833ED60F9685B40808AD20F3E62CE3F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF6BB5D3B872695B4080BF3CD3D47DCD3F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF59B9B12288695B4000BF1AC0F8B5CC3F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF566B8A956B695B4000BB46D4A90ACC3F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF5833ED60F9685B4000BED6994026CB3F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF520695585C685B40809320F41D50CA3F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF76FED88431685B4080B9E09A15B3C93F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF76FED88431685B408099407F4B87C83F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF630DFC1A1C685B4000B3002643EAC73F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF67BFD48DFF675B4000954A802014C73F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF72C63B50BF675B4080CD661C2A13C63F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF722AED3586675B4000B54CC52176C53F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF6ED0CF883D675B4080CDA88DB20AC53F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF625ADF50F0665B4000B54CC52176C53F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF701E64B268665B4000B0D289E304C63F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF614311A1FD655B4000AB584EA593C63F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF5C0B746C8B655B40808C1E6C6FBFC73F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF5FC8910B44655B408099407F4B87C83F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF6C286587F5645B40809A84A50317CA3F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF7702744118645B4000C494FB3627CC3F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF77716A53B4635B4000C10436A00BCD3F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF6A0077F28C635B400016D024816BCD3F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF76E0606550635B4000A492B635C5CD3F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF753889C7F9615B40808CBC85E5B7CE3F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF61B6A26F80615B400082A6FB8C0DCF3F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFE80B044807615B4000947D3318C0CF3F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF6A88BC1504615B40802208513D00D03F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF8540F57CFE605B4000F31F94C21FD03F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFC6308C00F6605B40804E29B90744D03F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF52E3C0A6EC605B40C050DBD64E68D03F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF7A5B4F98E3605B40C0350FD9A08CD03F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF666CA902DC605B404001D7AE06B1D03F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFCE8C1306D5605B4000467C0D7FD5D03F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF0647FA9BCD605B4040D7985E02FAD03F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF370E763CC6605B400043CE478E1ED13F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFFF5ADB37BE605B4080AB3AFA4B4AD13F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF795FFEA5CD605B40C06E0890CCA3D13F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF34643848CF605B4000E9C744BCA8D13F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF0AC32623E8605B408082BF78D6F3D13F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF76A247A002615B4040C2B956E043D23F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFCE0DAC012F615B40C036BB3C3D79D23F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF20F2B0FF63615B4000AA6E5DEDA5D23F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF8B2CB525C5615B40C0E9A7C97022D33F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF0FBDA623FA615B40C02C1D230E96D33F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF6771EA63FB615B40005167EDD799D33F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF8376B09314625B40003AEE5F1CE6D33F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF8A71BC773E635B40C0356D8102A4D33F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF8A32D5458A635B400004AA7EC6A1D33F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF46F89FE859645B40C09D21B0CDA1D33F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFA6D7DE28CB645B400031056C53D1D33F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF2F0005986B655B40001399A3DB13D43F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF770A8B87C0655B4040AEB0C7E15FD43F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF500F7F5728665B404019C463E672D43F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFFEA53403AD2665B40C0499B08ED85D43F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF9C4A3DE0A1675B40C043CDB6F14CD43F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF433E6558CC675B4080F2C9E45036D43F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF25F1545542685B400062305673F7D33F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF635829FDD7685B400015F9448A80D33F0000000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFEFFF`

How do I convert this geom to point x point y?

Comment: Do you want to extract vertices of the polygon as points?

Comment: yes sir, i want to make this polygon to lat and lng

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/33299771

Comment: you probably want `st_astext`

Comment: It is unclear if you want the centroid of the polygon or the vertices of the polygon.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ST_AsText('010600...');
```

returns:

```
st_astext
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 MULTIPOLYGON ZM (((109.638182917 0.304720466000006 0 -1.79769e+308,...
```